# Node.js, multer and req.body empty

Tags: node.js, upload, multer

Here it is my problem, I have a form where I can insert a file and a field but I receive only the file and not the parameter `test`! Why?

This is my code:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var port = 8000;
var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname.substring(0,file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.')) + '-' + Date.now() + file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.'),file.originalname.length));
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('fileUpload');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/api/upload',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Express server inizializzato sulla porta ' + port);
});
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" action="http://localhost:8000/api/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="test" />
            <input type="file" name="fileUpload" />
            <input type="submit" value="invia" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Did you try `req.body`?

Comment: @abdulbarik : yes, I try to return the req.body but return {}

Comment: It may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847293/uploading-a-file-and-passing-a-additional-parameter-with-multer

Comment: @abdulbarik  Thanks, I tried but nothing as changed, anyway as I wrote in my answer I resolved simply moving the request into the upload function ... why was there the problem? I don't know, the important thing is that now it works!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**2017 Update**

[From Readme](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage)

> Note that req.body might not have been fully populated yet. It depends on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.

I resolved my issue by reversing the order of my form object properties in the front end:

```
    var newFormObj  = new FormData();
    newFormObj.append('internalUserID', internalUserID);
    newFormObj.append('listingImage', this.binaryImages[image]);
```

---

On the backend:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(req.body.internalUserID) // YAY, IT'S POPULATED
    cb(null, 'listing-pics/')
  },                    
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }                     
});                     

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

Comment: why I got an empty req.body?

Comment: I received custom parameter after change sequence

Comment: I had the same problem when testing an API with Postman. Reordering the fields so that the file uploads were dead last fixed it for me. Thank you!!

Comment: Am I the only one to find this context weird ?

Comment: What to do if I am facing same problem with memoryStorage() instead of DiskStorage() ?

Comment: BRO you NAILED IT, Thank you so much.

Comment: Lol it actually worked, software is so fun isn't it guys

Comment: lol...It totally slipped my mind that the data is sequentially parsed. Saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

**You need to re-arrange the fields from frontend request, Below i will explain,**

> I am using **multer** to upload multiple files and single file in my
> **nodejs** application.

Postman request screenshot (**Mistaked**):
[image]

Postman request screenshot (**correct method**):
[image]

See the difference in order of fields. Always attach media files in last of the req content.

I had spent a 2 hours nearly to find this.
Definitly Work. Just try it.

Comment: how is your node code looks like ? are you using the middleware request.body ?

Comment: thanks, learned one more crutial thing: "attach media files in last of the req content"

Answer (score 15):

I resolve moving `req.body` at the end of the post function:

```
app.post('/api/upload?:test',function(req,res){

    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    console.log(req.body);

    });
});
```

If someone can tell me why I will happy to learn a new thing! But, for now, I resolved!

Comment: it works perfectly but why? can anybody explain this?

Comment: Hei, body-parser does not handle multipart/form-data bodies, but multer does. That's why you only get access to req.body inside the upload function.

Comment: @Angie please consider submitting your comment as an answer, it was the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `console.log(req.body)` inside `upload(req,res,function(err) {...})`

The default express body-parser cannot work with multipart/form-data, hence we use multer to parse form-data which is accessible inside your upload function.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually reorder the fields with javascript to make sure that fields are sent before files.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes here with a slightly more complex initial layout like the below, moving the upload function into the file with each route and using them there seems to have solved this for me. Why it's this temperamental, I don't know and honestly it's been a giant headache.

*It should be noted that I had a custom storage engine that streamed the file to disk which may have caused this issue however it only happened with 1 specific route which was functionally identical to several others which worked perfectly.*

Hope this might help someone else one day.

### Initial app layout

#### app.ts

```js
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';

import profilePicture from './routes/profile-picture.ts';

const upload = multer();

class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.app = express()
    }

    setRoutes() {
        this.app.use( '/upload', upload.single( 'profile' ), profilePicture );
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

#### profile-picture.ts

```js
import { Router } from 'express';

const profilePicture = Router();

profilePicture.post( '/', ( req, res, next ) => {
    console.log( req.body ); // This was always empty, regardless of field order
    // do something with req
}
```

### Updated layout that works for some reason

#### app.ts

```js
import express from 'express';

import profilePicture from './routes/profile-picture.ts';


class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.app = express()
    }

    setRoutes() {
        this.app.use( '/upload', profilePicture );
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

#### profile-picture.ts

```js
import { Router } from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';

const upload = multer();

const profilePicture = Router();

profilePicture.post( '/', upload.single( 'profile' ), ( req, res, next ) => {
    console.log( req.body ); // No longer empty, hooray!
    // do something with req
}
```