# I cannot upload files to the directory I specified using node js multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, mongodb

I created a web service using node js. I created a form with React interface and added user information and file upload. I save this information to mongodb. I want to save the file to the node js server using multer but did not add files to the directory I specified. What do I need to fix?

***Routes***

```
const express = require('express')
const User = require('../models/index')
const router = express.Router()
const multer = require('multer')

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null , file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

/* create new*/
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req,res)=>{

    user = new User({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password,
        img: req.file
    });

    user.save(()=>{
        res.json(user)
    })
});

/* find all users */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    User.find({},(err,data) =>{
        res.json(data)
    })
});

/* find user by id */
router.get('/:id',(req, res) =>{
    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, data) =>{
        res.json(data)
    })
});

/* delete user by id */
router.delete('/:id',async (req, res) =>{
    await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
    res.json({'message':'deleted'})
});

/* update */
router.put('/:id', async (req, res)=>{
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.is, req.body)
    res.json({'message':'updated'})
});

module.exports = router;
```

***Server/index.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const cors = require('cors');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?authSource=$[authSource] --username $[username]', {useNewUrlParser : true});
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use('/api',require('./routes/index'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port);

module.exports =  new mongoose.model('User', newSchema);
```

***React Side***

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: [],
            id: 0,
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            img: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        try {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api')
                .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({
                        users: res.data,
                        id: 0,
                        name: '',
                        email: '',
                        password: '',
                        img: ''
                    })
                })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    nameChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        })
    }

    emailChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            email: event.target.value
        })
    }

    passwordChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            password: event.target.value
        })
    }

    fileSelectedHandler = event =>{
        this.setState({
            img : event.target.files[0]
        })
    }

    submit(event, id) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData();

        data.append('name', this.state.name);
        data.append('password', this.state.password);
        data.append('email', this.state.email);
        data.append('image', this.state.img);

        if (id === 0) {
            axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api', data).then(()=>{
                this.componentDidMount()
            })

        } else {
            axios.put('http://localhost:8080/api/'+id, data).then(()=>{
                this.componentDidMount()
            })
        }
    }

    deleteUser(id) {
        try {
            axios.delete('http://localhost:8080/api/' + id)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.componentDidMount()
                })
            console.log('Deleted successfully.')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    editUser(id) {
        try {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/' + id)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data)
                    this.setState({
                        id:res.data._id,
                        name: res.data.name,
                        email: res.data.email,
                        password: res.data.password,
                        img : res.data.img.name
                    })
                })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s6">
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => this.submit(e, this.state.id)}>
                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <i className="material-icons prefix">person</i>
                            <input value={this.state.name} onChange={(e) => this.nameChange(e)} type="text" id="autocomplete-input"
                                   className="autocomplete" required/>
                            <label htmlFor="autocomplete-input">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <i className="material-icons prefix">mail</i>
                            <input value={this.state.email} onChange={(e) => this.emailChange(e)} type="email" id="autocomplete-input"
                                   className="autocomplete" required/>
                            <label htmlFor="autocomplete-input">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <i className="material-icons prefix">vpn_key</i>
                            <input value={this.state.password} onChange={(e) => this.passwordChange(e)} type="password" id="autocomplete-input"
                                   className="autocomplete" required/>
                            <label htmlFor="autocomplete-input">Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12">
                            <input type="file" name="file" onChange={(e) => this.fileSelectedHandler(e)}/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light right blue" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                            <i className="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="col s6">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Password</th>
                            <th>IMG</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {this.state.users.map(user =>
                            <tr key={user._id}>
                                <td>{user.name}</td>
                                <td>{user.email}</td>
                                <td>{user.password}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="./public/uploads/user.img.name" width="80"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button onClick={(e) => this.editUser(user._id)}
                                            className="btn waves-effect waves-light green" type="submit" name="action">
                                        <i className="material-icons right">edit</i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button onClick={(e) => this.deleteUser(user._id)}
                                            className="btn waves-effect waves-light red" type="submit" name="action">
                                        <i className="material-icons right">delete</i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two problems in your code.

On the server side the uploaded file is available under `file`-property on the request object not the `body`-property. Also you need to set the name to the uploaded file on the multer `single`-call, i.e. `image`:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req,res)=>{
...
    const image = req.file; // req.file contains the image
    // req.body holds the other fields like name, email, ...
...
});
```

On the react side you should send formData instead of a json (json is the default):

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('image', this.state.img);
data.append('email', this.state.name);
// ... append the remaining fields
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api', data)
.then(() => {
    this.componentDidMount()
});

// in the view also use the correct name
...
<input type="file" name="image" onChange={(e) => this.fileSelectedHandler(e)}/>
...
```

Comment: I tried to implement what you said, I edited the code blocks that I shared in my question. Can you check if I ask? This time there is no post request, previously the fields such as name, password, email could be registered on mongodb, but not currently. Is form data incorrect?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test it myself right now, but I think you need to add a body-parser instead of `express.json()`. Check these answers please -> 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197040/3761628
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61025053/3761628