# Uploading image and text using multer in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm using body-parser, express and `multer` in my NodeJS app.
I need to upload Image and few text fields in signup form. I'm using `multer` for this, I tried exactly the same thing suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847293/uploading-a-file-and-passing-a-additional-parameter-with-multer)

But I get empty object in `req.body`.
Files are being created in the destination folder, but `req.files.forEach` methods logs empty result.

Here is my code:

**Html front end code**

```
         <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile"  method="post" >

           <label>Name</label>
           <input type="text" placeholder=" Name" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">

           <label>Logo</label>
           <input type="file" placeholder="Logo" name="logo" id="logo" class="form-control">

           <button id="addform" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Profile</button>


        </form>
```

**Server Side Code:**

```
    app.post('/profile', function(req, res) {

      var storage = multer.diskStorage({
              destination: __dirname+'/file/uploads/'
          });
     var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).any();

          upload(req,res,function(err) {
              if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return res.end("Error uploading file.");
              } else {
                 console.log(req.body);
                 console.log(req.files);
                 req.files.forEach( function(f) {
                   console.log(f);
                   // and move file to final destination...  
                 });
                res.end("File has been uploaded");
              }
              });

    });
```

**Log output in Node:**

```
{}
[]
```

Comment: I have copied the exact code and tried it. And everything is working fine with the body and the file being logged to the console. So, maybe the problem with some other code? a middleware maybe? hope this helps.

Comment: is your isssue resolved?

Comment: Yes, actually I forgot to add '#' while referencing button click.

Comment: Please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try moving your Multer outside of the req body and try including filename parameter. I have modified your code.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname+'/file/uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

//passing multer as middleware
app.post('/profile',upload.any(), function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.body)


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck your form and make sure you have added name attribute to your input fields. I encountered same issue, and similarly was trying to find, but when reviewed multer documentation and found that it doesn't block req.body than I checked my form and found my other fields were not having `name` attribute only id was there.